# Textarea border hides issue on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some `textarea` elements. These elements have simple border in CSS. I have this issue that on Chrome border of this textarea disappears on browser scaling. On FF everything is fine.

So, this is good view:

[image]

And:

[image]

The style of this element:

```
border: 1px solid #318ab3;
background-color: white;
padding: 2px 5px 3px;
color: #318ab3;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
word-wrap: normal;
```

Is there any special webkit property which is responsible for this? Thx for help.

Comment: Could you provide some CSS with that? are you using with: 100%; on these elemens? You could run into an issue with box-sizing. Hard to tell on pictures

Comment: update - style of this element

Comment: There is `box-sizing: border-box` on every element. your textareas will have parent elements to make them this small, could you post the CSS of theese also?

Comment: Dude, remove the overflow: hidden property.

Comment: Dude, do you think I did't do this? This does't change anything...

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on fiddle ? This is what I created...If it helps you can take this and move forward to replicate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/XPwaS/1/